# Run time error when executing Like Operator in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to design a function that searches the first row for a certain term and then searches that column for the terms "Requirement" or "Function Change". Once it finds these terms it is to search the rows containing these terms and check for the term "Protocol" in a different column. I'm trying to accomplish this task using the Like Operator, but I keep getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error" pop up. Can anybody figure out why I might be getting this error? I've been looking at it for a while now and can't figure it out. Here's the code I have so far:

EDIT: Error pops up when the code gets to the first IF statement

```
Function CountProtocol() As Long

Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select
Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Unprotect

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, myTypeCol).Value Like "Functional Change" Or "Requirement" Then
            If Cells(i, myDescCol).Value Like "*protocol*" Then
                pro_count = pro_count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Requests of type ""Requirement"" or ""Functional Change"" that have ""Protocol"" in the description: " & pro_count

CountProtocol = Pro

End Function
```

EDIT: Here is the code where myTypeCol is assigned:

```
Function ColSearch(Heading As String) As Integer

Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select
Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Unprotect

myCol = Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Cells.Find(What:=Heading, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

ColSearch = myCol

End Function
```

It's called in the main subroutine like this:

```
myTypeCol = ColSearch("type")
myDescCol = ColSearch("description")
```

EDIT: This is another function I have that calls upon myTypeCol that works fine without error.

```
Function CountType() As Long

Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select
Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Unprotect

Dim type_count As Long
Dim type_count2 As Long
Dim type_sum As Long

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    type_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(myTypeCol & "2:" & myTypeCol & LastRow), "Requirement")
    type_count2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(myTypeCol & "2:" & myTypeCol & LastRow), "Functional Change")

    type_sum = type_count + type_count2

    MsgBox "Requests of type ""Requirement"" or ""Functional Change"": " & type_sum

CountType = Count

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare against the cell value after the `Or` operator like so:

```
Function CountProtocol() As Long

Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select
Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Unprotect

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, myTypeCol).Value Like "Functional Change" Or Cells(i, myTypeCol).Value Like "Requirement" Then
            If Cells(i, myDescCol).Value Like "*protocol*" Then
                pro_count = pro_count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Requests of type ""Requirement"" or ""Functional Change"" that have ""Protocol"" in the description: " & pro_count

CountProtocol = Pro

End Function
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. I still can't get it working though. When I make the edit you suggested above I get a "subscript out of range error at the "Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select" line. If I comment the Sheets lines out I get the original error again.

Comment: @user3783788 where is `myTypeCol` assigned? If it is not assigned (doesn't appear to be) then its default value is `0`, which will raise that 1004 error.

Comment: I have it assigned in a different function. I'll post an edit with the code.

Comment: Is that a global or module-level variable? Assigning it in the main subroutine will not have any affect, otherwise.

Comment: Alternatively, debug your code: what **is** the value of this variable when the error raises?

Comment: It says that mytypeCol = Empty when I step through the code. Sorry I'm pretty inexperienced in this, so I'm not quite sure the difference of a global and module-level variable.

Comment: What David means is unless the variable is defined somewhere like `Public myTypeCol As Integer` outside of the procedures (but needs to be within a module), nothing will be assigned to it.

Comment: I do not have it assigned like that anywhere, but I have another function that calls upon it in the same way and it works fine.

Comment: Ok I got it working. I had another macro open at the same time that was causing the "Subscript out of range" error. When I closed it the code worked with fix @Gareth added and calling the function that declares myTypeCol and myDescCol within the CountProtocol function. Thanks for all of the help.